# How can I take three consecutive terms of an array every nth terms?

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing

Can anyone guide me on how to select several consecutive terms of an array (e.g. 3) every nth element from a 1D vector using MATLAB codes?

E.g if my array is array = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12];
I want to take three consecutive terms jumping four afterwards, so the solution would be array_solution = [1 2 3 8 9 10];

Thank you very much.

Comment: That's not what I want, I edited the question so now I think it is better explained what I meant

Comment: got it. look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

use `bsxfun` to add two index vectors (column and row):

```
x = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12];
len = length(x); % total array length
c = 3; % number of consecutive elements
n = 4; % every nth element
idxs = bsxfun(@plus,(1:c)',0:(c+n):len);
y = x(idxs(:))

    y =

     [1     2     3     8     9    10]
```

Comment: Yeah, thank you very much that's exactly what I needed :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `bsxfun` (or function calls in general) for some reason, here is another way to get `c` consecutive elements every `n` elements.

```
x = 1:12;
c = 3;
n = 4;
% One of the two ranges in the indexing expression must be transposed
% so that MATLAB will apply vector expansion
y = x( (0:n+c:end-c) + (1:c)')

    y = 
        1    2    3
        8    9   10
```

You can also use this next snippet if you want the result to be a `1`x`m` vector.

```
idxs = (0:n+c:end-c) + (1:c)';
y = x(idxs(:))
```